# Kotlin Multiplatform Compose + Desktop + Web + Mobile

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

Is it possible at the moment to have a kotlin multiplatform project using compose for sharing the ui code for desktop, web, and mobile at the same time? All the examples i found only cover multiplatform with JS Front + Jvm Backend, or JVM Android + Desktop + Common Module, and I'm having trouble setting a project with all those at the same time.

I tried doing:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.1-rc2"
    id("com.android.library")
}
kotlin {
    android()
    jvm("desktop") {
       ...
    }
    js{
       ...
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
               ...
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
               ...
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
            }
        }
        val desktopMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
            }
        }
        val desktopTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting{
            dependencies{
                ...
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it produces the error:

```
:common:jsMain: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.1-rc2.
Required by:
    project :common
```

If i comment the JS related sections it works, or if i comment all the non-js related stuff it also works

Commenting everything compose-related also works

The problem is only when combining everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetbrains updated the github repo with some samples:

https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/experimental/examples

It is possible now with version "1.2.0-alpha01-dev675" but not all components work and it is still in a somewhat early alpha stage.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is: **No**, this is not possible at this time.

The JB team is working on such support, which can be tested in [these examples](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/experimental/examples), but for now it is experimental and there is no guarantee that it will be released any time soon. Compose JB version is now synced with Android Compose, so I expect that **1.2.0** will be released around the same time by both of them, even if Web support is not yet complete.

---

I have not been able to reproduce your error, but I assume that you have not removed `compose.foundation` and `compose.material` from the common dependencies.

At the moment, only `compose.runtime` is available for the common module, and this makes it almost impossible to do any layout at this point: even `Button` and `Text` are not available.

As you can see in the JS application example, `Text` is not imported from `androidx.compose.material.Text`, but from `org.jetbrains.compose.web.dom.Text`, which is a completely different element, so it cannot be used in a common module.

At this point, I would say that Compose JS is another framework that allows you to write UI in Compose style.

Comment: Found a way to do it :) Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

**

> This answer is not an exact answer to this question. The correct
> answer for this is the answer by @PhilipDukhov. However, this might
> help others who land on this page for finding a solution to the other
> problem I am just leaving it here.  For more info read comments
> between me and @PhilipDukhov for this answer.

**

### Yes, it is possible to have all three modules in a single project. TLDR

I did some workarounds and managed to get all things in a single project i.e

1. Compose for Desktop
2. Compose for Android
3. Compose for Web

**Suggestion Before You Go Further**

> Although below code snippets works and by going through you will be
> able to achieve what you want actually. I personally recommend you to
> just go to the Github repository [here](https://github.com/PSPanishetti/ComposeMultiplatform) . I think it will save time
> if you are creating a new project. However if you are adding web
> module to current KMM project continue reading.

The problem can be fixed by keeping the correct dependencies

So the project structure should be something like this

[image]

Note: If you are creating a new KMM project you will have only common, desktop, and android modules.(As you already know)

Step 1: You need to add the a folder to root (where the android, common,desktop folder is located) call it as **web**(should not matter)

Step 2: Add several folders to this newly created directory web
your web directory should look something like this

[image]

Note : Dont add build (its autogenerated) add only

```
src/jsMain
   -kotlin
   -resources
src/jsTest 
    -kotlin
   -resources
```

and create a file called **build.gradle.kts**

Step 3: Change the content of this newly added Gradle file to something like this

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.0"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            testTask {
                testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                    useFirefox()
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.web.core)
                implementation(compose.runtime)
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 4: And Add Main.kt to `jsMain/kotlin` with following content

```
 renderComposable(rootElementId = "root") {
    Div(
        attrs = {
            // specify attributes here
            style {
                // specify inline style here
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text("A text in <div>")
    }
}
```

Step 4 : Add index.html to jsMain/resources with content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MultiplatformTest Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="web.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Note: web.js file mentioned in the above snippet is sensitive and the project
> generated you need to make sure it is web.js only or else the
> folder_name.js which you created in step 1

Step 5: Finally add web module to settings.gradle.kts file

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }
    
}
rootProject.name = "MultiplatformTest"


include(":android")
include(":desktop")
include(":common")
include(":web")  // Note web module is included here
```

I have created a repo check this repo and you can use it as a template for your projects

Link to the repo: https://github.com/PSPanishetti/ComposeMultiplatform

### If you get any doubts feel free to ask them.

Comment: Link only answer is rarely can help. Please provide significant parts of your solution. The question was about sharing composable views between web, desktop and android, but your shared module only supports desktop/android platforms, which means you cannot import any of composables declared in common module into your web module.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov yes agree... Will edit it later

Comment: as I said in my first comment, you are answering some other question. You have different modules for each platform, and you have to build the UI in the web/desktop modules independently of each other, but the author is asking how to build the UI from one common multiplatform module.

Comment: Oh, I got it ...   @PhilipDukhov